# org.postgresql.util.PSQLException "violates unique constraint" during DefaultLockRegistry#acquire

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-integration

I am using spring-integration to create distributed locks. As in `org.springframework.integration.jdbc.lock.DefaultLockRepository#acquire` it is normal to have `DuplicateKeyExceptions`, I assume when another node already holds the lock, and this case is handled explicitly.

However, using Postgres, I do not get a DuplicateKeyException, but a native `org.postgresql.util.PSQLException`, when the unique constraint is violated:

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "int_lock_pk"
  Detail: Key (lock_key, region)=(2c294c0e-ff49-4e14-8d3e-d5c04ef269d8, DEFAULT) already exists.
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2477)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2190)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:300)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:428)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:354)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:169)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PgPreparedStatement.java:136)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:61)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.lambda$update$0(JdbcTemplate.java:867)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:617)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:862)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:917)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:927)
    at org.springframework.integration.jdbc.lock.DefaultLockRepository.acquire(DefaultLockRepository.java:163)
```

This case is *not* handeled and the lock acquisition is aborted. How can I cope with that?

Cheers,
Stefan

Edit: The exception is wrapped into

```
Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: PreparedStatementCallback; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [DELETE FROM INT_LOCK WHERE REGION=? AND LOCK_KEY=? AND CREATED_DATE<?]; SQL state [25P02]; error code [0]; ERROR: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block; nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
```

Answer (score 0):

You can override that `DefaultLockRepository.acquire()` in your own extension to catch that exception and perform logic respectively.

On the other hand it is not clear why that `SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator` doesn't handle such an exception properly.

According out-of-the-box config the Postgres coding is like this:

```
<bean id="PostgreSQL" name="Postgres" class="org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodes">
    <property name="useSqlStateForTranslation">
        <value>true</value>
    </property>
    <property name="badSqlGrammarCodes">
        <value>03000,42000,42601,42602,42622,42804,42P01</value>
    </property>
    <property name="duplicateKeyCodes">
        <value>23505</value>
    </property>
```

So, that `25P02` is not presented. Not sure what is going on.

We probably can provide an overridden `DefaultLockRepository` ctor to inject a `JdbcTemplate` to let you to provide a custom `SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator` to handle such an exception.

But that's too much: I would say to override that method and catch such an exception would be much simpler solution.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I found this (quite old) thread meanwhile: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/27963/postgres-requires-commit-or-rollback-after-exception, which suggests, that any erroneous statements in PostgreSQL automatically leads to the whole transaction being aborted. If that is true (and it looks like it is) I wonder if I can use the LockRepository at all in the way it is intended...

Comment: Well, that's the whole point of the `DefaultLockRepository.acquire()`. It is transactional and we need to finish transaction as fast as possible after taking the lock entry in the table or fail. Therefore rollback is fully OK for your use-case when you can't obtain the entry in the table. Essentially this is indeed the logic behind that `acquire()` implementation.

Comment: Alright, then I will try and overwrite that method! I will report here if it worked out.